# In Moon, what would the rescue unit have done to Sam?

Tags: moon-movie

In the movie Moon, Sam is told  a rescue ship is coming for him. But from later events, we know that

> The corporation had been hiding the fact that they were using clones as slave labour. So they would never have let Sam off the moon.

So what was the "rescue" mission going to do?

Comment: As much as the answer is obvious, it doesn't deserve a downvote :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They never planned to rescue him. It was a lie. You basically answered your own question. If a Sam discovers the truth or lives about [three years](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Moon) he must be eliminated and a new Sam will be installed / activated.

"Sam" has been there long enough for the systems to become corrupt and show images from his past existences. There is no rescue plan. That is the whole point.

The "rescue" crew are armed because they are on a salvage / reset mission. They kill any Sams that are aware of their situation or are over 3 years old. They only show up to keep the business running, not to help the current Sam. Sam is no different than a screwdriver or tire to them.

Thanks to [Plutor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1973/plutor), also, for answering this in a different form.

Comment: And yet, we did see a spaceship coming in

Comment: @ShantnuTiwari, "If a Sam discovers the truth or lives about three years he must be eliminated". The ship was coming in with someone to eliminate the now-outdated clone and reset the system/base.

Comment: @ShantnuTiwari Yes, but it's not a rescue ship. Most likely a cleanup squad.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. In the last scene, when the cleanup crew open the old Sam's buggy, it looked to me like they were holding a machine gun. @Meat Trademark, do you mind adding these points to your answer, viz that the crew were coming to eliminate the extra clones?

Comment: @Shantnu Tiwari - Done. I hope it does justice to your request.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's look at what the company said the "rescue squad" was coming for.

From [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Moon.html).

> **OVERMEYERS**
>
> We don't want you to take any
>   unnecessary risks. You're too
>   important to us.
>
> **THOMPSON**
>
> You're to stay put, understand?
>
> **OVERMEYERS**
>
> It's an order.
>
> **THOMPSON**
>
> It's an order, Sam. From Lunar.
>   Stay put.
>
> **OVERMEYERS**
>
> We're going to send a Rescue Unit
>   to tend to the stalled harvester
>   and get the base back on its
>   feet.
>
> --snip --
>
> **THOMPSON**
>
> Yeah, you resting up, Sam? You'd
>   better be you bastard.
>
> **OVERMEYERS**
>
> Enjoy it while it lasts! We've
>   got good news.
>
> **THOMPSON**
>
> The Jupiter Program had to be put
>   on hiatus, so we've got a few
>   free pairs of hands --
>
> **OVERMEYERS**
>
> We've managed to secure you a
>   Rescue Unit ahead of schedule.
>
> **THOMPSON**
>
> Rescue Unit Eliza.
>
> *A SHOT/STILL PHOTO of Rescue Unit ELIZA. A meaner group of
>   sons-of-bitches you have never seen. These guys make the
>   rescue team from Apocalypse Now look like The New Kids on
>   the Block.*
>
> **OVERMEYERS**
>
> They've been stationed on Goliath
>   19 for the last couple of months.
>
> **THOMPSON** (O.S.)
>
> Eliza's been in transit for the
>   last day....we expect them to
>   reach you in approximately 14
>   hours.
>
> **OVERMEYERS** (O.S.)
>
> Commence to jump for joy!
>
> **THOMPSON** (O.S.)
>
> You'll be back to work in no
>   time.
>
> *Now back on **OVERMEYERS** and **THOMPSON**.*
>
> **OVERMEYERS**
>
> Eliza is bringing you something
>   special, Sam. Compliments of the
>   company.
>
> **THOMPSON**
>
> A hooker!
>
> **OVERMEYERS**
>
> No not a hooker. What's wrong
>   with you? It's a little something
>   to drink, Sam, that's all, our
>   way of patting you on the back
>   for all that you've been through.
>
> **THOMPSON**
>
> In the meantime, keep resting up,
>   and hang in there.
>
> **OVERMEYERS**
>
> Yeah you hang in there, Sam. Over
>   and out.

The "rescue crew" Eliza is supposedly coming to fix the harvester and "get the base back on its feet." Sam 2 doesn't believe them.

> **SAM 1**
>
> They're sending a Rescue Unit?
>     Why?
>
> **SAM 2**
>
> To fix the stalled harvester.
>     They didn't think I was up to it.
>
> **SAM 1**
>
> Then I'm going back.
>
> **SAM 2** gives **SAM 1** a perplexed look.
>
> **SAM 1** (CONT'D)
>
> I've done my three years. That's
>   it for me --
>
> **SAM 2** is shaking his head slowly.
>
> **SAM 1** (CONT'D)
>
> What?
>
> **SAM 2**
>
> Is that what you really think?
>
> **SAM 1**
>
> I've got a contract --
>
> **SAM 2**
>
> You're a fucking clone! You don't
>   have shit!
>
> At once **SAM 1** and **SAM 2** ROCKET to their feet -- right in
>    each others faces, on the BRINK of BLOWS.
>
> **SAM 1**
>
> I'm going home!
>
> **SAM 2**
>
> You're not going anywhere!
>
> -- snip --
>
> **SAM 2**
>
> I've been thinking. That Rescue
>   Unit -- Eliza -- they'll be here
>   in less than fourteen hours. I
>   don't know about you but I'd like
>   to figure out where we stand
>   before they get here.
>
> **SAM 1**
>
> Absolutely.
>
> **SAM 2**
>
> Ostensibly they're coming to deal
>   with the stalled harvester. We
>   both know that isn't true.
>   (then)
>   They're coming to dig your body
>   out of that rover. They think
>   you're in there.
>
> -- snip --
>
> **SAM 2**
>
> If that Rescue Unit finds the two
>   of us awake at the same time,
>   they'll kill us both for sure.

Sam 2 doesn't believe them. But he is *not* just being paranoid. Gerty confirms the danger.

> **GERTY**
>
> If the Rescue Unit examine my
>   memory banks they will discover
>   what has taken place over the
>   last week. As you know I record
>   everything. If they are
>   suspicious, the first thing they
>   will do is search my memory
>   banks, and this would put you in
>   considerable danger.

So, while it is never *explicitly* stated exactly what the "rescue" crew of the Eliza intended to do when they arrived, it is *heavily* implied that they were coming there to kill any active clone(s) they find (possibly using the "drink" mentioned) and reset the system/station.

Comment: The script you're quoting from is not the same as the "shooting" script. Some scenes and dialogue are different from the movie. The same logic applies though. Bad news for "Sam."

Comment: @MeatTrademark If you've got a link to the final script, I'd be happy to update the answer when I have a chance.

Comment: I do not have one, nor was I disagreeing with you in any manner. "Leaked" scripts often differ from the scripts used on set. Not all script drafts end up online. Even if there is no difference in the "shooting" script, rewrites can happen in the editing bay. I hope you did not take offense at my comment. I compared that script to the movie and they differ enough to not be an authoritative reference about the movie. No plot points or anything major differs; just some scenes and dialogue, as I mentioned. I wouldn't worry about updating unless you plan to transcribe the film.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I didn't take offense at all. I'd just like to have the most accurate answer I can.